# how to make a list in python from a string and using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

My string is

```
strs = "[ Policyholder Name ][CA Insurer ][Policy Number ][Inception Date ][Expiration Date ][Street Address ][City ][Zip Code ][FEIN ][Bureau Number ] "
```

i want to make list by getting the values in the `[]`.

My final output should be,

```
filter_list = ['Policyholder Name','CA Insurer','Policy Number','Inception Date','Expiration Date','Street Address','City','Zip Code','FEIN','Bureau Number']
```

I tried this regular expression, but i am getting a empty list as output.

```
m=re.compile('</[/>(.*?)</]/>', re.DOTALL).findall(strs)
```

Comment: i tried using this, m=re.compile('</[/>(.*?)</]/>', re.DOTALL).findall(strs)

Comment: `[x for x in re.split('\[\s*(.+?)\s*\]', strs.strip()) if x]`